# How to embed an image in windows target?

Tags: haxe, nme, openfl

I tried to add embed = true in project xml like this:

```
<assets embed="true" path="Assets" rename="assets" include="*" exclude="openfl.svg" />
```

But if I try to delete an image from assets folder, then run the exe file, the image will not be displayed, thus, it still loaded form assets folder.

Can some one help?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks every body, I found the answer of Joshua here [Embeding and reading image assets when deploying to Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17078148/embeding-and-reading-image-assets-when-deploying-to-windows)

But who to know where to read about the answer in the openFL documentation?